# c++ Return Value Optization

Tags: c++, reference, rvo

I am hoping someone can shed some light on what RVO does in g++.   I have some third party software that I need to modify, and I'd like to optimize it as best possible, but I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly RVO does, and when it kicks in.   My current structure looks something like:

```
class Foo {
private:
    Bar     myBar;
public:
    Bar &getBar() { return myBar; };
};
```

Where callers typically use it as so:

```
int x = foo.getBar().getX();
```

Because the return is a reference, there is no copy of the structure required, which is nice for performance reasons.

I need to modify `Foo` to use `Bar2` instead of `Bar` for its internal structure, but, I need to keep the `getBar()` interface available for the third party callers.  I have a function `convertBar2ToBar(const struct Bar2 &bar2, struct Bar &bar)`, which can efficiently convert between the two structure types, but I'm concerned, as if I do:

```
Bar& Foo::getBar() { Bar rt; convertBar2ToBar(myBar2, rt); return rt }
```

Then this returns a reference to a variable on the stack, which can be scribbled on.   I can alternatively modify the program to return a copy of `rt` as so:

```
Bar Foo::getBar() { Bar rt; convertBar2ToBar(myBar2, rt); return rt }
```

But now I'm worried that my `Foo.getBar().getX()` will be slow because it has to convert of `Bar2` to `rt` (unavoidable), and then do a copy 'rt' to a local context of the caller (avoidable???)...   I'm not clear whether RVO can prevent the copy, and if so, what exactly is going on under the hood.

Comment: Stop worrying about performance the first thing you do, that will only lead to *premature optimization* which is generally bad. Instead try to make a nice, working, readable, well-documented and well-commented, and maintainable program. If the performance of an optimized release build is not "good enough" (and most of the time "good enough" *is* good enough) then measure, benchmark and profile to find the hot-spots and bottlenecks and fix *only* those, with comments about why you're doing it, and what the code is doing.

Comment: Intuition is the worst guide for optimization. Measure and compare. For example, it may seem like returning a reference optimal, but have you considered the potential cost of dereferencing?

Comment: you say you have to keep the `getBar()` interface as is, but then you also should not change its return type from a reference to a value. This may break callers

Comment: I'd be more worried about changing the return type to a copy from a reference. It seems to me that it contradicts your stated goal to preserve the interface.

Comment: `Bar Foo::getBar()` and `Bar & Foo::getBar()` are hugely different functions. Callers will have different expectations for both those declarations. For example, assume `Bar` has some public `int x` member. If you remove the reference code like `myFoo.getBar().x += 1;` may silently stop working.

Comment: _"Then this returns a reference to a variable on the stack, which can be scribbled on"_ This betrays a lack of comprehension of the _abstraction_ that C++ is. Don't worry about actual memory being "scribbled on": worry about undefined behaviour that could do literally anything.

Comment: A good example for why returning references to class internals is a bad thing in the first place.

Comment: @nh_: You don't also mean `const` references, do you?

Comment: @tobi303 -- yes, it may break callers.   So far everything I looked at treats the return as a variable as opposed to a reference, but there's lots of calls to this, so I haven't gone over each of them yet.   I think the original author just employed the convention of returning references with the idea that it was faster, and was treating them as variables anyways.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: This is for the data path of a router (i.e. every tcp packet will call this), and therefore optimization is unfortunately necessary.   Decreasing the instruction count even slightly will effect maximum throughput rate.   I tend to agree with your philosophy, for most other sections of the code, but this definitely requires optimization.

Comment: @John returning a reference from a getter makes the getter rather pointless and the member could be public as well. Actually I would prefer a public member rather and a getter that returns a non-const reference, because the getter pretends that there is encapsulation when in fact there isnt

Comment: @tobi303 sounds logical.  I'm new to this code, and somewhat new to C++ in general (I'm typically a C developer, so I don't know the ins and outs of C++ for embedded systems).    I'm not keen on the idea of returning references in the first place, as it seems to have a lot of sharp sticks attached to it, but I also don't want to totally rewrite this code... sigh...

Comment: @John Then just make sure the reasons are well-documented/-commented. :)

Comment: You can also try *Bar getBar() const { ... }*, since it doesn't modify the member of Foo.  Compiler can optimize even more by doing so.

Comment: How about: `class Foo {
private:
    Bar     myBar;
    Bar2    myBar2;
public:
    Bar &getBar() { convertBar2ToBar(myBar2, myBar); return myBar; };
};` ? (you still have issue that modifications on `getBar()` are not reported to `myBar2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not clear whether RVO can prevent the copy

Yes, that is its purpose.

<strike>Furthermore, it's *required* to prevent the copy as of C++17.</strike>
 <sup>*(sorry no, it's not; that's for returning a prvalue; still, you can rely on NRVO in reality)*</sup>

And if the copy is expensive enough to care about any of this in the first place, then it probably also ought to be *movable* in which case we again do not care about the cost.

> and if so, what exactly is going on under the hood.

It doesn't matter.

But, on your 2017 PC, roughly speaking, `rt` will be "created" in the caller's stack frame rather than locally here. Thus, no copy required at all.

(And, indeed, don't return a reference to a local variable.)

Comment: when you say _movable_, what are you referring to?

Comment: @John: Google "C++ move semantics" or turn to the chapter on "move semantics" in your C++11 book.